# Thread/Global Variable Confusion

Tags: c++builder, vcl

So I've got an application in Embarcadero's RAD Studio that I'm working on.  It is a VCL application with a separate thread that is handling I/O off board the PC.  Inside a function in the thread I have code that looks like this....

```
 if(run) 
 {
     /* run I/O code here */
 }else       
 {
     /* stop I/O here */
 }
```

run is a global boolean variable in the thread's .h file.  It's state is changed by a button on the form.  When debugging the app, a breakpoint on the first line of the code shows the value of "run" toggling true and false with the button press however the code ALWAYS executes the first part of the if statement and run the I/O code??  What gives?  Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you initializing run?

Comment: That should not be happening, based on what you've described. It's impossible to say why it is, because we can't see the rest of your code.

Comment: run is being initialized in the .h file like this....

     boolean run = true;

Comment: "Inside a function".  If there's nothing inside the function itself that changes `run`, then perhaps you should take a look at call sites?

Comment: @martinarcher "*run is being initialized in the .h file like this.... boolean run = true;*" - that means every .cpp file that includes the .h file will get its own copy of the `run` variable, and you should be getting "duplicate symbol" warnings from the linker. The correct way to handle a global variable in a .h file is to declare the variable as `extern` only (`extern bool run;`) and then define and initialize the actual variable in *one* .cpp file (`bool run = true`). OTOH, if you use `TThread` for your thread, you don't need `run` at all, use the `TThread::Terminated` property instead.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  I figured it was somehow creating a copy of the run variable in each cpp file.  Thanks for the info.  I'll try extern.  I will need the run variable since this thread will run until he application terminates and the run variable will switch what it's current role is.  I'll try that tonight and let you know how it works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Just a question about defining the extern....does the scope of the definition apply as usual?  AKA should it be defined at the top of a cpp file as a "global" to take care of the extern defines in the multiple h files.  Thanks

Comment: @martinarcher: Yes, the actual variable will have to be declared as a global in one of the .cpp files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - that worked like a champ.  Thanks so much for the help.  Does Embarcadero know that their debugger is not thread safe?  The debugger was showing the value for the main thread's cpp file while the breakpoint was set in the thread's cpp file.

Comment: The debugger debugs what the compiler/linker produces. If the compiler produces multiple copies of the same `run` variable, it is anyone's guess which one the linker will actually keep and put in the executable.  That is not a threading issue.